# jQuery place text beside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

```
<h:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{userBean.un}"
                styleClass="form-control" required="true"
                onfocus="popupMessage(this, 'username');">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)"></f:validateRegex>
            </h:inputText>

function popupMessage(element, stringVal) {
                var position = $(element).position();
                if(stringVal === "username"){
                    $( element ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top ) ;
                }else if(stringVal === "password"){

                }else{

                }
            }
```

I am trying to use this code to put a message beside an input field. Above you can see the element and my script. What I want is based on the input type whether it be username or password I want a message to appear beside the text field which will tell people what to enter. I plan to put an `onblur`event on the inputs as well to make the message go away.

I can get text to show in the element in the console view but nothing on the page. How do I position this message properly? ("note the message now is just the position of the calling element")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-To positon text message beside input text field. You have to use the Jquery .css() method. 

-The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document. You have to use the right method which helps you.
```

Jquery .text(string) method helps to display text on the matched selector but not for positioning it.

```
$(element).css({
                "left" :position.left
                ,"top" :position.top
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Primefaces, why don't you use `<p:tooltip>` component? You may easily achieve what you are trying to do with Primefaces Tooltip.